# AutoFocus doesn't work in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with autoFocus. It doesn't work for me, but using it:

```
<input onChange={this.handleName} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name..." type="text" autoFocus />
```

Answer (score 13):

## None of these worked for me:

```
<input type="text" autoFocus        .../>
<input type="text" autoFocus={true} .../>
<input type="text" autoFocus="true" .../>
<input type="text" autoFocus="autofocus" .../>
```

…even though in each case, the web inspector showed that `<input type="text" autofocus .../>` was rendered

[image: input with autofocus rendered]
[image]

Perhaps it's because of [this phenomenon](https://blog.danieljohnson.io/react-ref-autofocus/), I'm not sure:

> If you render your React component into a detached element, React will call `focus()` too soon. This will result in the `input` not focusing when your React tree gets added to the DOM.

## This **did** work for me:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function SignIn() {
  const inputElement = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputElement.current) {
      inputElement.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <form action="...">
            <input
                  ref={inputElement} // yes, this is working in Chrome on Mac 
                  type="text" // allows username also; type 'email' woud insist on '@' sign
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Email address"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  required
                  ...
                />
        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That's strategy #2 from [Daniel Johnson](https://blog.danieljohnson.io/react-ref-autofocus/)

[image: autofocus to this input when page loads]

Comment: Thank you for copying that quote from the (now defunct) blog! I was having focus issues when using React Portals and this made me realize that I was dynamically generating and inserting the container node into the document.body too late (in `useEffect()`). After moving that to earlier in the code, problem solved!

Answer (score 4):

Likely something else you are doing that is causing it to fail. It works fine in this simple example:

```js
const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return ( 
      <input
       placeholder = "Name..."
       type = "text"
       autoFocus 
      / >
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So autoFocus works only if value is set? I need to focus an empty input.

Comment: No, are you going to even make an attempt to test these things yourself? Updated example with no value set.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't work for me. Is there a problem with React version?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on the functional react component as the autoFocus attribute did not work out of the box:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';

const FeebackForm = () => {
  const autoFocusFn = useCallback(element => (element ? element.focus() : null), []);

  return (
    <form action="...">
      <input type="text" name="customerName" ref={autoFocusFn} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default FeebackForm;
```

Comment: It worked for me, util I built and stopped working. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

For React function components when you get the error

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
> this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const InputField = () => {
  const inputElement = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    inputElement.current?.focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <form action="...">
      <input type="text" innerRef={inputElement} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

If you use typescript and the compiler complains

> Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

initialize inputElement with

`const inputElement = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);`

Answer (score 0):

I had two Input's which I applied autoFocus to, one worked and the other didn't. They were both reactstrap Input fields:

```
import { Button, Input } from 'reactstrap';
```

I discovered that one had a type and no name, which was the one that worked. So I changed the other to be the same and it started working:

```
      <Input
        autoFocus="autofocus"
        id="code"
        type="text"
        value={props.codeValue}
        onChange={props.onCodeChange}
        onKeyPress={event => {
          if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            confirmCode();
          }
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

place that "autoFocus" infront of "input"

```
<input autoFocus type='text' ...others />
```

idk but this worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a conditional input component that appears post page is loaded on some user interaction, use [react cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) design to focus the input element.

jsx:
`{ this.state.showInput && <input ref={ref => {this.inputRef = ref}} /> }`

Class components:

```
this.setState({showInput: true},
   () => {
      this.inputRef && this.inputRef.focus()
   }
)
```

Functional components:

```
useEffect(() => {
   return () => {
      this.inputRef && this.inputRef.focus()
    }
}, [showInput])
```

Answer (score -2):

If auto focus doesn't work for you then you can try using the `.focus()` function of javascript, which will always work :)

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
}

<input id="name" onChange={this.handleName} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name..." type="text" autoFocus />
```

Comment: This is exactly what `autoFocus` in react DOM is doing.

Comment: @Sulthan , true that. Though it doesn't harm if it is mentioned I think.

Comment: using document is not advisable in react

Comment: In React, don't interact with document object directly. Using `refs` is much better approach.